# When to call addChildViewController

Tags: ios

I'm trying to have something similar to a UINavigationController so I can customize the animations.  To start, I'm just using Apple stock animations.  Here's my containerViewController:

```
- (void)loadView {
    // Set up content view
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    _containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.view = _containerView;

}

- (id)initWithInitialViewController:(UIViewController *)vc {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _currentViewController = vc;

        [self addChildViewController:_currentViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:_currentViewController.view];
        [self didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        _subViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:_currentViewController, nil];
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)pushChildViewController:(UIViewController *)vc animation:(UIViewAnimationOptions)animation {
    vc.view.frame = _containerView.frame;
    [self addChildViewController:vc];

    [self transitionFromViewController:_currentViewController toViewController:vc duration:0.3 options:animation animations:^{

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
        [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.subViewControllers addObject:vc];
    }];
}

- (void)popChildViewController:(UIViewController *)vc WithAnimation:(UIViewAnimationOptions)animation {
    // Check that there is a view controller to pop to
    if ([self.subViewControllers count] <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    NSInteger idx = [self.subViewControllers count] - 1;
    UIViewController *toViewController = [_subViewControllers objectAtIndex:idx];
    [vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [self transitionFromViewController:vc toViewController:toViewController duration:0.3 options:animation animations:^{

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
        [vc removeFromParentViewController];
        [self didMoveToParentViewController:toViewController];
        [self.subViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:idx];
    }];
}
```

I have this ContainerViewcontroller as my rootViewController of the window.  I can add my initial viewController and push a view controller.  When I try to pop though, I get

```
ContainerViewController[65240:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SecondViewController: 0x8072130>.
```

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.  I figured my initialViewController is still underneath the secondViewController.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is what's causing your problem, but shouldn't this:

```
[self didMoveToParentViewController:toViewController];
```

be:

```
[toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Also, I'm not sure what you're doing with the subViewControllers array. It seems to be a duplication of the childViewControllers array that is already a property of a UIViewController.

One other thing I'm not sure is right. In your pop method your toViewController is the last controller in the _subViewControllers array. Don't you want it to be the second to last? Shouldn't the last be the one you're popping? You're popping vc, which is a controller you're passing in to the method, I don't understand that.

This is the way I've made a navigation like controller. In its containment behavior, it acts like a navigation controller, but without a navigation bar, and allows for different transition animations:

```
@implementation ViewController

-(id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *) rootVC {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self addChildViewController:rootVC];
        rootVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:rootVC.view];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *) vc animation:(UIViewAnimationOptions)animation {
    vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.childViewControllers[self.childViewControllers.count -2] toViewController:vc duration:1 options:animation animations:nil
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            NSLog(@"%@",self.childViewControllers);
    }];
}

-(void)popViewControllerAnimation:(UIViewAnimationOptions)animation {
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.childViewControllers.lastObject toViewController:self.childViewControllers[self.childViewControllers.count -2] duration:1 options:animation animations:nil
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [self.childViewControllers.lastObject removeFromParentViewController];
                                NSLog(@"%@",self.childViewControllers);
                            }];
}

-(void)popToRootControllerAnimation:(UIViewAnimationOptions)animation {
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.childViewControllers.lastObject toViewController:self.childViewControllers[0] duration:1 options:animation animations:nil
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                for (int i = self.childViewControllers.count -1; i>0; i--) {
                                    [self.childViewControllers[i] removeFromParentViewController];
                                }
                                NSLog(@"%@",self.childViewControllers);
                            }];
}
```

After Edit:  I was able to duplicate the back button function with this controller by adding a navigation bar to all my controllers in IB (including in the one that is the custom container controller). I added a bar button to any controllers that will be pushed, and set their titles to nil (I got some glitches if I left the title as "item"). Deleting that title makes the button disappear (in IB) but you can still make connections to it in the scene list. I added an IBOutlet to it, and added this code to get the function I wanted:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (self.isMovingToParentViewController) {
        self.backButton.title = [self.parentViewController.childViewControllers[self.parentViewController.childViewControllers.count -2] navigationItem].title;
    }else{
        self.backButton.title = [self.parentViewController.childViewControllers[self.parentViewController.childViewControllers.count -3] title];
    }
}
```

I've shown two different ways that worked to access a title -- in IB you can set a title for the controller which I used in the else clause, or you can use the navigationItem title as I did in the if part of the clause. The "-3" in the else clause is necessary because at the time viewWillAppear is called, the controller that is being popped is still in the childViewControllers array.

Comment: Follow up question, I noticed that when you use transitionFromViewController: you call it from what looks like to be the ParentViewController, or the Container of the child view controllers.  Is that correct?  If so, why?  Should all the controllers be transitioned that way from the parent?

Comment: @Crystal, Yes, in this case, I'm doing all the transitions from the parent "faux navigation" controller. This works the same way as it would with a real navigation controller, where you call self.navigationController pushViewController:animated: from one of the children. The only difference is that here you use self.parentViewController push ...

Comment: @Crystal, You don't have to use that transition code in the parent, I just think it work best in this case. I have put that code in the children -- then you have to sent that method to self.parentViewController.

Comment: when you've implemented your own faux navigation controller or other container controllers, what have you done to get access to the navigationItem property or navigationController.  I'm guessing I can't just use that stuff for free anymore...

Comment: @Crystal, I haven't tried to do that yet, since that wasn't my focus. But, no, I don't think you will get that for free.

Comment: @Crystal, Actually, I just tried adding navigation bars to all my controllers of my test project, and that does give you access to the navigationItem property. I was able to duplicate the behavior of the navigation controller back button (except that the button I added in IB didn't have the point on the left) by adding a few lines of code in the viewWillAppear: method. I've updated my post to show that.

Comment: thanks again for the help.  For some reason, I couldn't get it working the way you suggested.  My UINavigationBar's title would not change.  Instead I put my ContainerViewController as the rootViewcontroller of a UINavigationController and referenced the navigation bar with self.parentViewController.navigationItem to set bar button items, titles, etc.  Similarly to what you said, the little back arrow does not get added for me either.  But at least I have something working finally thanks to your help!

Answer (score 4):

`addChildViewController` should be called first

For adding / removing, you can refer to this great category and have no worry when to call it:

[UIViewController + Container](https://github.com/xelvenone/UIViewController--Container-)

```
- (void)containerAddChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController {

    [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

- (void)containerRemoveChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController {

    [childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [childViewController removeFromParentViewController];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to rdelmar's answer you should not be calling addView/removeFromSuperview `transitionFromViewController` does this for you, from the documentation:

> This method adds the second view controller’s view to the view
>   hierarchy and then performs the animations defined in your animations
>   block. After the animation completes, it removes the first view
>   controller’s view from the view hierarchy.

Comment: thanks I had that issue, I tried to "improve" the Apple implementation and didn't look at the transitionFromViewController docs... in the end transitionFromViewController doesn't really do anything for you, much better to do it all by hand and just use UIView animate... I wish I could upvote you +10